# Usage of underscore as argument of a macro function

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

In **C**, what's the meaning of an underscore as a macro parameter?

```
#define FUNC(_) VALUE
```

Is it a dummy argument? any example for a use-case in which it'll fit?

Comment: yeah, it's a dummy argument if it's not used, but there's nothing special about the name. It could have been called `x` or `foo` or whatever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, the code can be read as:

> `FUNC` takes a single argument, but it doesn't care what it is. No matter what is passed in, `VALUE` is the result.

A single `_` is a valid identifier in C, and is thus suitable for use as a macro argument name.

Comment: well, then if the define points to a value there's no need for such thing; for other cases I get it. thanks.

Comment: I took your example literally, so that is how it is interpreted. Since `_` is a valid identifier, it can be used within the macro body if the programmer chooses to do so. It is a bad choice, however, because it hurts readability.

Comment: Is there anything special about the underscore, or does it just have the agreed upon meaning of an unneeded parameter?

Comment: @Carcigenicate: A `_` is a valid identifier. There is no convention to use it as an unneeded parameter. My interpretation of that is based on the fact that the substitution text `VALUE` does not use `_` in any way.

Answer (score 7):

The `_` has no special meaning, I suppose they used it because it looks like if the argument is not there.

The `_` is just a valid identifier, and hence it's taken so the macro requires one parameter, but it keeps the macro definition looking as if there was no parameter.

```
#define FUNC(ignoredParameter) VALUE
```

would be exaclty the same.